# Removing kaspersky free antivirus fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, kaspersky

I'm trying to remove kaspersky antivirus free from my computer but I'm not able to - if I go to apps & features and try to remove it there, I'm receiving error as on screenshot below:
[image: kaspersky error]
I tried running kaspersky installer to remove it but when I choose 'uninstall' in installer window it shows similar error and just crashes, how could I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove it from *Control Panel > Programs and Features*, and follow the prompts.

See the documentation
[How to remove a Kaspersky Lab application](https://support.kaspersky.com/12783#block0).

If this does not work, try the
[Kaspersky Kavremover](https://support.kaspersky.com/1464):

> Kavremover is a free tool for removing Kaspersky Lab applications from your device safely and in full.

Comment: apps & features in windows 10 is exactly same thing as programs and features in control panel, already tried control panel too and it seems to display same error

Comment: Do you have another anti-virus installed?

Comment: nope, only kaspersky, I installed it because I was buying parental control software from them and I was like, hm, why not, I'll install AV, everybody reccomends it, and then it litearlly broke my ubuntu subsystem so it cannot connect to internet, maybe this kaspersky release is corrupted or something, because even though I disabled everything I could in it it's still blocking internet connections and is un-uninstallable

Comment: I added the Kaspersky remover tool. Reboot when it finishes.

Comment: works perfectly fine, every software that was non functioning properly because of kaspersky works fine aswell, thanks! kaspersky remover is way to go

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered 'overwriting' it with a new installation of Kaspersky? Post that just try unistalling it.

That would just install it once again on top of the existing version and perhaps fix any installation problems that is preventing you from uninstalling it.

I'm guessing you're doing this on admin rights.

Another option I could think of would be to use the Safe Mode and then uninstalling it from there.